# VS Code React build messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

When I build and run my react solution I get hundreds of warnings like the below. Is there a way to turn off particular warnings?

[image: Warnings]

Comment: Fix the linting rules? It looks like you're linting transpiled and bundled code, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you have a linter running so you can see these issues before you build? [Here's](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) a great linting extension for vscode.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of some of the lines causing warnings?

Comment: Disable your linter for the build output directory. Without showing your setup (both react build and linter) we can't help you though.